# Laravel 8 Passport Registration: UserController action not executed

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-passport, laravel-8

I read the official tuturial of Passport and several examples for REST API. However, when I post a registration request, I could only get a html page which is not showing error, but not related to the response.

The breakpoint I put inside the `register` action of **UserController** has never been reached.

Please let me know if the complete source code is required for debugging.

Thank you.

The official tutorials:
[Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport)

Examples:

[Example 1](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/passport-tutorial-auth-user-access) [Example 2](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-rest-api-with-passport-authentication-tutorial/) [Example](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-rest-api-with-passport-authentication-tutorialexample.html)

**Breakpoint:**

[image: UserController breakpoint]

**routes\api.php**

```
Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/register', [UserController::class, 'register']);

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('games', GameController::class);
});
```

Postman request:

[image: Postman registration result][image: HTML Result]

Comment: Are you sure the routes are correctly placed in your API.php file? Shouldn't they be in the default web.php file? Often the API errors have a different guard or middleware, I think your problem is that your API middleware is redirecting to a login page.  Our does it return an error page?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Thank you for your explanation. It is not mentioned in the tutorials, but it actually went to the index route of default ``web.php`` file. I thought when I use /api/action, it should directly execute the REST API instead of the HTML pages. Please let me know if I missed any essential settings. Regards.